# public non generic Constructor of List that cant be used

Tags: c#, list

When I right click on the List() Class and click "go to definition" I can see some original Microsoft code with all the members of the class.
So thats nothing new but the first line is

```
[...]public List();
```

So it seems like the List class has a public non generic constructor. This is what this line says to me but it is obv wrong because you can´t create a no generic list. 
So why is there this line of code in the List class definition?
Why does it exist?

Comment: There's no such thing as a generic constructor. The class to which that constructor belongs is a generic class. That's the parameterless constructor for the generic class. The generic class requires a type parameter. C# doesn't require the class definition to reiterate the type parameter on definitions; no reason to.

Comment: What `List` class are you referring to?

Comment: The type `List<T>` is generic, with this type itself having a generic type parameter `T` (the type of the items in a list). `List<T>` has a constructor with no arguments (`public List() {...}`). Why would this constructor need to specify its own generic type parameter(s), in your opinion?

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because the type itself - `List<T>` is generic, you can use the generic argument `T` in a constructor. For example, `List<T>` has this constructor:

```
public List (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> collection);
```

But regardless of what generic type is used when we call that constructor...

```
var stringList = new List<string>(arrayOfStrings collection);
var intList = new List<int>(listOfInt collection);
```

...the constructor itself doesn't need to be generic - that is, it doesn't need have a generic type argument. We're specifying that when we create the object.

If we had to include the generic arguments again in the constructor, like this...

```
public List<T>();
public List<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> collection);
```

...it wouldn't add any new information.

What if we were creating a new class and realized that we needed to add generic arguments? We could have constructors that have nothing to do with those generic arguments, like this:

```
public class SomeGenericClass<T, T2>
{
    SomeGenericClass(int value)
    { /// }

    SomeGenericClass(string somethingElse)
    { /// }
}
```

We'd have to change all of the constructors anyway, which would be pointless since the constructors themselves aren't changing.